# Is it valid to add customized members when processing errors in JSONAPI

Tags: json, json-api

I've read the [json specs](http://jsonapi.org/format/#errors) and [examples](http://jsonapi.org/examples/#error-objects-multiple-errors) for processing multiple errors and was just wondering if it was valid/acceptable to add custom member fields to our response.

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "changeid": "1",
      "result": "true",
      "detail": "Successful"
    },
    {
      "changeid": "2",
      "result": "false",
      "detail": "Error detail message"
    },
    {
      "changeid": "3",
      "result": "",
      "detail": "Skipped"
    }
  ]
}
```